# Apply function to subset of data frame

Tags: r, split, dataframe, bigdata, subset

I have a huge data frame like this

```
 head(newdata)
      V1 V2 V3 V4    V5    V6      V7      V8
1     a 1941 2 14 -73.90 38.60 US009239     4
2     b 1941 2 14 -74.00 36.90 US009239     6
3     c 1941 2 14 -74.00 35.40 US009239     4
5     d 1941 2 15 -74.00 32.60 US009239     7
6     f 1941 2 15 -73.80 31.70 US009239v    1
```

and what I would like to do is to perform some operation on every subset of data characterised by the same V7. I tried splitting it with

```
split(data, list(data$V7), drop = TRUE)
```

and then calculating the min and max of V8 for every element of the list, but it take too much memory and is really slow.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following scheme may be helpful

```
indices <- 1:nrow(newdata)
groups <- split(indices, newdata$V7)
lapply(groups, function(idx) {
   subdata <- data[idx,]
   # some operations on subdata...
})
```

It prevents R for creating multiple sub-`data.frames` at once, and thus may reduce the memory usage. You may also try calling `gc(TRUE)` to force garbage collection between each iteration of `lapply`.

However, I'm conscious that this is not a highly elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

with dplyr you can do:

```
 data %>% group_by(V7) %>% summarise(Max=max(V8), Min=min(V8))
```

hth

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(Max=max(V8), Min=min(V8)), by=V7]
```